# why does CTAD result in a vector with iterators, not integers?

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, ctad

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> initv { 42, 31, 7 };

    std::vector      v1{initv.begin(), initv.end()};  // CTAD
    std::vector<int> v2{initv.begin(), initv.end()};

    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(v1)>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(v2)>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >
```

CTAD produces a vector with iterators, not integers.

Is this correct, given that `std::vector` has a constructor that takes iterators ?

Comment: Because as implemened, list initialization was a mistake that still feeds of the life force of the language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because of how you initialize the vector.  With

```
std::vector      v1{initv.begin(), initv.end()};
```

You are doing *direct-list-initialization* which uses the `std::initializer_list` constructor and the list contains 2 `std::vector<int>::iterator`s.  This is why it deduces for iterators.

If you switch to using parentheses instead like

```
std::vector      v1(initv.begin(), initv.end());
```

then you are no longer using the `std::initializer_list` constructor and instead using the iterator range constructor which will correctly deduce the `value_type` of the iterators.

---

To summerize, when you use `{}` you are signaling you are using a list of initializers, so that is what is used if it is available.

If you would like to take a deep dive down the rabbit hole that is initialization in C++, I strongly recommend watching Nicolai Josuttis CPPCON talk [“The Nightmare of Initialization in C++”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs)